# 16.04: How to get the recommended intel-microcode package to fix hyper-threading issue?

Tags: 16.04, intel, cpu

The Debian mailing list has a post relevant to some Skylake and Kaby Lake users: [[WARNING] Intel Skylake/Kaby Lake processors: broken hyper-threading](https://lists.debian.org/debian-devel/2017/06/msg00308.html)

Users are to run

```
grep name /proc/cpuinfo | sort -u
```

to obtain their processor details and then to check
http://ark.intel.com/products/codename/37572/Skylake or http://ark.intel.com/products/codename/82879/Kaby-Lake as appropriate.

<s>If their processor is listed, they should next run</s>

```
grep -q '^flags.*[[:space:]]ht[[:space:]]' /proc/cpuinfo && \
echo "Hyper-threading is supported"
```

According to a [follow-up post](https://lists.debian.org/debian-devel/2017/06/msg00318.html), the above command which I've struck through is not reliable and users need to run `lscpu` and check if

> the lscpu output reports: "Thread(s) per core: 2", that means
>   hyper-threading is enabled and supported.

If hyper-threading is supported, advice is provided for both Skylake and Kaby Lake.

I have an affected Skylake processor on **16.04** which *can* be fixed because

```
grep -E 'model|stepping' /proc/cpuinfo | sort -u
```

returns

```
model       : 78
model name  : Intel(R) Core(TM) i3-6006U CPU @ 2.00GHz
stepping    : 3
```

For such processors the fix suggested is to install

> the non-free "intel-microcode" package
>      with base version 3.20170511.1, and reboot the system.  THIS IS
>      THE RECOMMENDED SOLUTION FOR THESE SYSTEMS, AS IT FIXES OTHER
>      PROCESSOR ISSUES AS WELL.

But the 16.04 repo shows me an older version:

```
apt policy intel-microcode
intel-microcode:
Installed: (none)
Candidate: 3.20151106.1
Version table:
3.20151106.1 500
500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/restricted amd64 Packages
```

Is it possible to get the recommended version and, if it is possible, how can I do so?

Edit: I found https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/xenial/+package/intel-microcode but they all seem to be older versions.

Second edit: https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/intel-microcode has the relevant update but it is for *Artful Aadvark*.

Comment: The intel-microcode AND a BIOS update are required to fix this problem. Check your computer's manufacturer's web site for BIOS updates.

Comment: Unfortunately, a discussion with Acer support suggests that they will soon release BIOS updates but none of them will be usable for linux because they will all be Windows executables. So for some of us BIOS updates are out of the question.

Comment: So use command: **`lscpu | grep -e Model -e Step -e ^CPU\(s\) -e Thread`**

Comment: Fix has been committed to the proposed channel in Ubuntu 17.04; see https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/xenial/+source/intel-microcode/+bug/1700373/comments/28.

Comment: @edwinksl This seems to not contain updates for Kaby Lake, at least not for mine. Those haven't been released yet AFAIK.

Comment: Got the update today on Ubuntu 17.04

Comment: As you can see here:
https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/intel-microcode/3.20170707.1~ubuntu16.04.0/+build/13159263
there is a build for xenial-proposed, which you can install with
`wget "https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/intel-microcode/3.20170707.1~ubuntu16.04.0/+build/13159263/+files/intel-microcode_3.20170707.1~ubuntu16.04.0_amd64.deb"` and 
`dpkg -i intel-microcode_3.20170707.1~ubuntu16.04.0_amd64.deb`.

Answer (score 5):

[Install the latest official package manually](http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/pool/non-free/i/intel-microcode/). i.e. for 64-bit OS:

```
wget http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/pool/non-free/i/intel-microcode/intel-microcode_3.20170511.1~bpo8+1_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i intel-microcode_3.20170511.1~bpo8+1_amd64.deb
```

Reboot the machine, and you're set. **ALSO**, you need to install the latest BIOS update from your machine. Consult with your computer's manufacturer for the latest official BIOS update.

Comment: How is BIOS related? New BIOS may have the new microcode. In that case you don't need the deb.

Comment: @Pilot6 Not 100% sure. Just going by what I found in the only post so far (another site) that had concrete instructions on resolving this.

Comment: I would recommend *not* doing this.

See https://wiki.debian.org/DontBreakDebian#Don.27t_make_a_FrankenDebian

Answer (score 3):

You can install the package that is for `artful`.

This package contains binary firmware. It is release independent.

Comment: "It is release independent." That's not entirely true according to some people in the Freenode #ubuntu channel. The reason that some Ubuntu releases lag behind with the intel-microcode package is because newer versions of intel-microcode require appropriate kernel support. This is why you see Trusty still has an old intel-microcode package even though Trusty is a LTS release and it's supposed to be still supported.

Answer (score 0):

You can install the bios update using windows pe.

Windows setup media contains windows pe. The cmd shell can be brought up by pressing shift + f10 to access the bios executable updater.