# Ubuntu doesn't reboot

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2

I left Linux around 8 years a go, now I want to go back to it. I installed Ubuntu 16.04.2 as dual boot on MSI Leopard ge62 6QF. It wasn't booting before adding

```
acpi=off
```

after **quiet splash** in the kernel line of GRUB. After this it boots successfully. Now when I wanted to reboot/Poweroff the system, I opened the terminal and wrote:

```
sudo reboot
```

It starts rebooting but it is freezing when it gets to

```
Reboot: Restarting System
```

I tried all Google suggestions like replacing `acpi=force` and decreasing  the timeout but unfortunately none of them worked and the system doesn't boot anymore.

What else can I do?

Comment: Preferably install the current 17.04. No parameters should be required. Install the recommended Nvidia drivers at Additional Drivers and everything should work as expected.

Comment: should i change something as acpi ? the current acpi is off should i remove it or what ? should i install 17? or 16 lts is fine

Comment: As I said, with 17.04, no parameters. There are reasons for keeping a LTS in many situations. For high end and relatively new hardware, newer is always better.

Comment: i did read about what the meaning of LTS, it does mean long term support right ? that is why i want to keep the current LTS but no problem i will install 17 thank you :)

Comment: Good luck with the next version with long time support, 18.04 LTS :-)

Comment: You can still keep 16.04 and install the 4.10 kernel 17.04 is using. Plus you can install an even newer kernel than 17.04 is using like 4.11 or 4.12: https://askubuntu.com/questions/879888/how-do-i-update-kernel-to-the-latest-mainline-version/879920#879920

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your laptop has the **Intel i7-6700HQ** 6th generation CPU known as "Skylake". It also has a **NVidia Geforce GTX 970M** GPU. To eliminate the dedicated Nvidia GPU from the equation you can temporarily work with only the integrated Intel GPU in the short term.

When using Skylake you made need updates:

- [Ubuntu 15.10: Various "types" of freezes and now unexpected shutdown](https://askubuntu.com/questions/827939/ubuntu-15-10-various-types-of-freezes-and-now-unexpected-shutdown/828027#828027)
- ["W: Possible missing firmware for module i915_bpo" when updating initramfs](https://askubuntu.com/questions/811453/w-possible-missing-firmware-for-module-i915-bpo-when-updating-initramfs/879250#879250)
- [Ubuntu doesn't reboot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/941252/ubuntu-doesnt-reboot)

These are some of the answers I've written but there are many great answers others have written:

- [No version of Ubuntu can be installed with any Skylake 6th generation Intel processor](https://askubuntu.com/questions/691216/no-version-of-ubuntu-can-be-installed-with-any-skylake-6th-generation-intel-proc)
- [16.04: How to get the recommended intel-microcode package to fix hyper-threading issue?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/929274/16-04-how-to-get-the-recommended-intel-microcode-package-to-fix-hyper-threading)
- [Ubuntu 16.04 Skylake 6th Generation Screen Flickering](https://askubuntu.com/questions/752743/ubuntu-16-04-skylake-6th-generation-screen-flickering)
- [Ubuntu 16.04 Skylake overheating](https://askubuntu.com/questions/830404/ubuntu-16-04-skylake-overheating)

Unfortunately not enough is known about your specific problems to point your question as a duplicate of an existing one.

One last thing to change is the Intel c-state max idle:

- [How to set intel_idle.max_cstate=1](https://askubuntu.com/questions/749349/how-to-set-intel-idle-max-cstate-1)
- [System freezes completely with Intel Bay Trail](https://askubuntu.com/questions/803640/system-freezes-completely-with-intel-bay-trail)

Although targeted at Intel BayTrail users it seems to have improved things for other Intel CPU users as well. If these fixes work I regard them as a work-around to make life better in the short term until a real solution is found.

Comment: Yes Already did it and you are correct